# Importance of equilibrium constant

Tags: equilibrium

Here i am going to let out a doubt of mine which has been bothering me since high school about equilibrium constant. Let's say we have a reaction.

$A+B\rightarrow C+D$. When we say reversible reactions, we say that $A$ and $B$ react to form $C$ and $D$ and after that $C$ and $D$ again react back to form $A$ and $B$. *When does this reacting back to form $A$ and $B$ occur?*

Now,the equilibrium stage of a reaction. What's the importance of the equilibrium constant and why was the constant defined to be $\frac{[C][D]}{[A][B]}$. I have always struggled understanding why the equilibrium constant is defined in that way.

Answer (score 3):

The reverse reaction occurs simultaneously to the forward reaction, if all products are present.

We say the reaction is at [chemical equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_equilibrium) when rates of both reactions are equal and the net change is zero. The fact this equilibrium is dynamic and not static can be observed via [isotopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope) exchange.

The [equilibrium constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_constant) is defined that way (variants use partial pressures, molar fractions or activities), because, well, that expression is at the given temperature constant, assuming the equilibrium state.